# upper bound for a function f

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z^3e^{z^2}-e^{3z^2}$.

For $R>0$, I need an upper bound for

$$\max_{z\in\bar{B(0,R)}}|f(z)|,$$

which will look nice if I take its natural logarithm, that is

$$\ln|\{\max_{z\in\bar{B(0,R)}}|f(z)|\}|.$$

Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: What conditions on an upper bound do you want?  How about $R^3e^{R^2}+e^{3R^2}$?

Comment: I also thought of that but I don't find the $\ln|R^3 e^{R^2} + e^{3R^2}|=\ln|e^{R^2}(R^3+e^{2R^2})|=R^2+\ln|R^3+e^{2R^2}|$ nice.

Comment: How about $e^{R^3+3R^2}$?

Comment: How can I get that ($e^{R^3+3R^2})$? Thanks!

Comment: I mean why is $|z^3 e^{z^2} - e^{3z^2}|\leq |e^{R^3 + 3R^2}|$?

Comment: I gave an answer with $R^3+3R^2+1$ as the exponent instead.  I'm not sure about $R^3+3R^2$.

Comment: Okay now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Jeana: I just saw how I could improve the bound to $e^{R^3+3R^2}$ and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, then $e^a+e^b<e^{a+b}+1$, and $a<e^{a}-1$.  Thus

$$R^3e^{R^2}+e^{3R^2}=e^{R^2}(R^3+e^{2R^2})<e^{R^2}(e^{R^3}+e^{2R^2}-1)<e^{R^2}e^{R^3+2R^2}=e^{R^3+3R^2}.$$

This can be improved using $1+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}<e^x$ for $x>0$, so that $\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\right)^3<e^x-1$, which implies that $x^3<e^{\sqrt[3]{6}x}-1$.  Thus another bound that works is $e^{3R^2+\sqrt[3]{6}R}$.